# Spring Webclient connection not closed properly

Tags: spring-boot, netty, spring-webflux, reactor-netty, spring-webclient

I am trying to make HTTP calls using Springboot-Reactive webclient. I am getting connection closed by remote server error.

Please find the following code which uses Webclient to make rest call.

```
Mono<String> post(String url, JSONObject body) {

        Mono<String> result = webClient().post().uri(url)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(body))
                .exchange().log()
                .flatMap { clientResponse ->
                        return clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class)
                }
        return result
    }
```

Webclient created code:

```
WebClient webClient() {
    TcpClient tcpClient = TcpClient.create()
    .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 30000)          
    .doOnConnected { connection ->
        connection.addHandlerLast(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.TRACE))
        connection.addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(30))
        .addHandlerLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler(30))
    }
    tcpClient.wiretap(true)

    ReactorClientHttpConnector httpConnector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.from(tcpClient))


    return WebClient.builder()
        .clientConnector(httpConnector)
        .build()
}
```

I am getting the following logs after the first call:

```
2019-04-10 15:26:31.534  INFO 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-04-10 15:26:31.534  INFO 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-04-10 15:26:31.544  INFO 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 10 ms
2019-04-10 15:26:31.820 DEBUG 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] reactor.netty.tcp.TcpResources           : [tcp] resources will use the default LoopResources: DefaultLoopResources {prefix=reactor-tcp, daemon=true, selectCount=4, workerCount=4}
2019-04-10 15:26:31.821 DEBUG 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] reactor.netty.tcp.TcpResources           : [tcp] resources will use the default ConnectionProvider: PooledConnectionProvider {name=tcp, poolFactory=reactor.netty.resources.ConnectionProvider$$Lambda$377/205810452@3af356f}
2019-04-10 15:26:32.127 DEBUG 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] r.netty.resources.DefaultLoopEpoll       : Default Epoll support : false
2019-04-10 15:26:32.128 DEBUG 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] r.netty.resources.DefaultLoopKQueue      : Default KQueue support : false
2019-04-10 15:26:32.131 DEBUG 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] i.n.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup    : -Dio.netty.eventLoopThreads: 8
2019-04-10 15:26:32.161 DEBUG 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop        : -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization: false
2019-04-10 15:26:32.161 DEBUG 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop        : -Dio.netty.selectorAutoRebuildThreshold: 512
2019-04-10 15:26:32.165 DEBUG 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] i.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent  : org.jctools-core.MpscChunkedArrayQueue: available
2019-04-10 15:26:32.297  INFO 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] reactor.Mono.SwitchIfEmpty.1             : onSubscribe(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.SwitchIfEmptySubscriber)
2019-04-10 15:26:32.316  INFO 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] reactor.Mono.SwitchIfEmpty.1             : request(unbounded)
2019-04-10 15:26:32.362 DEBUG 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl             : netty-tcnative not in the classpath; OpenSslEngine will be unavailable.
2019-04-10 15:26:32.903 DEBUG 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] io.netty.handler.ssl.JdkSslContext       : Default protocols (JDK): [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1] 
2019-04-10 15:26:32.903 DEBUG 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] io.netty.handler.ssl.JdkSslContext       : Default cipher suites (JDK): [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]
2019-04-10 15:26:32.929 DEBUG 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : Creating new client pool [tcp] for remoteserver.host.com:443
2019-04-10 15:26:32.945 DEBUG 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelId        : -Dio.netty.processId: 235344 (auto-detected)
2019-04-10 15:26:33.242 DEBUG 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelId        : -Dio.netty.machineId: 1c:4d:70:ff:fe:a5:c9:6d (auto-detected)
2019-04-10 15:26:33.287 DEBUG 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil              : -Dio.netty.allocator.type: pooled
2019-04-10 15:26:33.287 DEBUG 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil              : -Dio.netty.threadLocalDirectBufferSize: 0
2019-04-10 15:26:33.287 DEBUG 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil              : -Dio.netty.maxThreadLocalCharBufferSize: 16384
2019-04-10 15:26:33.309 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0xb38d8bca] Created new pooled channel, now 0 active connections and 1 inactive connections
2019-04-10 15:26:33.343 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf          : -Dio.netty.buffer.checkAccessible: true
2019-04-10 15:26:33.344 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf          : -Dio.netty.buffer.checkBounds: true
2019-04-10 15:26:33.346 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] i.n.util.ResourceLeakDetectorFactory     : Loaded default ResourceLeakDetector: io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector@403ca90
2019-04-10 15:26:33.374 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.tcp.SslProvider            : [id: 0xb38d8bca] SSL enabled using engine SSLEngineImpl and SNI remoteserver.host.com:443
2019-04-10 15:26:33.386 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.channel.BootstrapHandlers  : [id: 0xb38d8bca] Initialized pipeline DefaultChannelPipeline{(reactor.left.sslHandler = io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler), (reactor.left.sslReader = reactor.netty.tcp.SslProvider$SslReadHandler), (BootstrapHandlers$BootstrapInitializerHandler#0 = reactor.netty.channel.BootstrapHandlers$BootstrapInitializerHandler), (SimpleChannelPool$1#0 = io.netty.channel.pool.SimpleChannelPool$1), (reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
2019-04-10 15:26:33.617 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] io.netty.util.Recycler                   : -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread: 4096
2019-04-10 15:26:33.618 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] io.netty.util.Recycler                   : -Dio.netty.recycler.maxSharedCapacityFactor: 2
2019-04-10 15:26:33.618 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] io.netty.util.Recycler                   : -Dio.netty.recycler.linkCapacity: 16
2019-04-10 15:26:33.618 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] io.netty.util.Recycler                   : -Dio.netty.recycler.ratio: 8
2019-04-10 15:26:33.648 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Registering pool release on close event for channel
2019-04-10 15:26:33.648 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Channel connected, now 1 active connections and 0 inactive connections
2019-04-10 15:26:33.855 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler          : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] HANDSHAKEN: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
2019-04-10 15:26:33.857 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] onStateChange(PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443]}, [connected])
2019-04-10 15:26:33.887 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] onStateChange(GET{uri=/, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443]}}, [configured])
2019-04-10 15:26:33.890 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect    : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Handler is being applied: {uri=https://remoteserver.host.com/api/v1/Test, method=POST}
2019-04-10 15:26:34.014 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler     : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Writing object DefaultHttpRequest(decodeResult: success, version: HTTP/1.1)
POST /api/v1/Test HTTP/1.1
user-agent: ReactorNetty/0.8.6.RELEASE
host: remoteserver.host.com
Accept: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 28
2019-04-10 15:26:34.043 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler     : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Writing object 
2019-04-10 15:26:34.050 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler     : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Writing object EmptyLastHttpContent
2019-04-10 15:26:34.051 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] onStateChange(POST{uri=/api/v1/Test, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443]}}, [request_sent])
2019-04-10 15:26:34.229 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.ReactorNetty               : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Added decoder [LoggingHandler] at the end of the user pipeline, full pipeline: [reactor.left.sslHandler, reactor.left.httpCodec, LoggingHandler, reactor.right.reactiveBridge, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]
2019-04-10 15:26:34.254 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.ReactorNetty               : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Added decoder [ReadTimeoutHandler] at the end of the user pipeline, full pipeline: [reactor.left.sslHandler, reactor.left.httpCodec, LoggingHandler, ReadTimeoutHandler, reactor.right.reactiveBridge, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]
2019-04-10 15:26:34.271 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.ReactorNetty               : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Added decoder [WriteTimeoutHandler] at the end of the user pipeline, full pipeline: [reactor.left.sslHandler, reactor.left.httpCodec, LoggingHandler, ReadTimeoutHandler, WriteTimeoutHandler, reactor.right.reactiveBridge, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]
2019-04-10 15:26:34.274 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.ReactorNetty               : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Added decoder [IdleStateHandler] at the end of the user pipeline, full pipeline: [reactor.left.sslHandler, reactor.left.httpCodec, LoggingHandler, ReadTimeoutHandler, WriteTimeoutHandler, IdleStateHandler, reactor.right.reactiveBridge, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]
2019-04-10 15:26:34.289 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.http.client.HttpClientOperations     : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Received response (auto-read:false) : [Transfer-Encoding=chunked, Content-Type=application/json; charset=utf-8, Server=Kestrel, Server-Timing=api;desc=dotREZ API;dur=7, cache;desc=Cache read/write;ct=1;dur=1, total;dur=8, X-Powered-By=ASP.NET, Set-Cookie=dtCookie=17$0D7C3AB4BE87B44D72811D72E8C4878F; Path=/; Domain=.test.com, Date=Wed, 10 Apr 2019 21:26:37 GMT, Set-Cookie=dotrez=67235850.20480.0000; path=/; Httponly; Secure]
2019-04-10 15:26:34.289 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] onStateChange(POST{uri=/api/v1/Test, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443]}}, [response_received])
2019-04-10 15:26:34.295  INFO 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.Mono.SwitchIfEmpty.1             : onNext(org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultClientResponse@5119d40e)
2019-04-10 15:26:34.337 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive        : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Subscribing inbound receiver [pending: 0, cancelled:false, inboundDone: false]
2019-04-10 15:26:34.338  INFO 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.Mono.MapFuseable.2               : | onSubscribe([Fuseable] FluxMapFuseable.MapFuseableSubscriber)
2019-04-10 15:26:34.338  INFO 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.Mono.MapFuseable.2               : | request(unbounded)
2019-04-10 15:26:34.338  INFO 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.Mono.SwitchIfEmpty.1             : onComplete()
2019-04-10 15:26:34.346 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.http.client.HttpClientOperations     : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Received last HTTP packet
2019-04-10 15:26:34.347  INFO 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.Mono.MapFuseable.2               : | onNext({"data":{"result"}})
2019-04-10 15:26:34.354  INFO 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.Mono.MapFuseable.2               : | onComplete()
2019-04-10 15:26:34.355 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.ReactorNetty               : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Removed handler: LoggingHandler, pipeline: DefaultChannelPipeline{(reactor.left.sslHandler = io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler), (reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec), (ReadTimeoutHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler), (WriteTimeoutHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.WriteTimeoutHandler), (IdleStateHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
2019-04-10 15:26:34.355 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.ReactorNetty               : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Removed handler: ReadTimeoutHandler, pipeline: DefaultChannelPipeline{(reactor.left.sslHandler = io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler), (reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec), (WriteTimeoutHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.WriteTimeoutHandler), (IdleStateHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
2019-04-10 15:26:34.355 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.ReactorNetty               : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Removed handler: WriteTimeoutHandler, pipeline: DefaultChannelPipeline{(reactor.left.sslHandler = io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler), (reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec), (IdleStateHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
2019-04-10 15:26:34.355 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.ReactorNetty               : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Removed handler: IdleStateHandler, pipeline: DefaultChannelPipeline{(reactor.left.sslHandler = io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler), (reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
2019-04-10 15:26:34.355 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] onStateChange(POST{uri=/api/v1/Test, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443]}}, [disconnecting])
2019-04-10 15:26:34.355 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Releasing channel
2019-04-10 15:26:34.356 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Channel cleaned, now 0 active connections and 1 inactive connections
```

The connection becomes inactive and when I make the call after some time (say 10 mins). I am getting the following log:

```
2019-04-10 15:34:27.178  INFO 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] reactor.Mono.SwitchIfEmpty.3             : onSubscribe(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.SwitchIfEmptySubscriber)
2019-04-10 15:34:27.179  INFO 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] reactor.Mono.SwitchIfEmpty.3             : request(unbounded)
2019-04-10 15:34:27.184 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Channel acquired, now 1 active connections and 0 inactive connections
2019-04-10 15:34:27.184 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect    : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Handler is being applied: {uri=https://remoteserver.host.com/api/v1/Test, method=POST}
2019-04-10 15:34:27.185 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler     : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Writing object DefaultHttpRequest(decodeResult: success, version: HTTP/1.1)
POST /api/v1/Test HTTP/1.1
user-agent: ReactorNetty/0.8.6.RELEASE
host: remoteserver.host.com
Accept: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 28
2019-04-10 15:34:27.187 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler     : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Writing object 
2019-04-10 15:34:27.187 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler     : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Writing object EmptyLastHttpContent
2019-04-10 15:34:27.188 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] onStateChange(POST{uri=/api/v1/Test, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443]}}, [request_sent])
2019-04-10 15:34:27.188 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.ReactorNetty               : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Added decoder [LoggingHandler] at the end of the user pipeline, full pipeline: [reactor.left.sslHandler, reactor.left.httpCodec, LoggingHandler, reactor.right.reactiveBridge, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]
2019-04-10 15:34:27.189 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.ReactorNetty               : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Added decoder [ReadTimeoutHandler] at the end of the user pipeline, full pipeline: [reactor.left.sslHandler, reactor.left.httpCodec, LoggingHandler, ReadTimeoutHandler, reactor.right.reactiveBridge, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]
2019-04-10 15:34:27.189 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.ReactorNetty               : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Added decoder [WriteTimeoutHandler] at the end of the user pipeline, full pipeline: [reactor.left.sslHandler, reactor.left.httpCodec, LoggingHandler, ReadTimeoutHandler, WriteTimeoutHandler, reactor.right.reactiveBridge, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]
2019-04-10 15:34:27.189 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.ReactorNetty               : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Added decoder [IdleStateHandler] at the end of the user pipeline, full pipeline: [reactor.left.sslHandler, reactor.left.httpCodec, LoggingHandler, ReadTimeoutHandler, WriteTimeoutHandler, IdleStateHandler, reactor.right.reactiveBridge, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]
2019-04-10 15:34:46.395  WARN 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect    : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 - R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] The connection observed an error

java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:288) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.34.Final.jar:4.1.34.Final]
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1125) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.34.Final.jar:4.1.34.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:347) ~[netty-transport-4.1.34.Final.jar:4.1.34.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:148) ~[netty-transport-4.1.34.Final.jar:4.1.34.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:677) [netty-transport-4.1.34.Final.jar:4.1.34.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:612) [netty-transport-4.1.34.Final.jar:4.1.34.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:529) [netty-transport-4.1.34.Final.jar:4.1.34.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:491) [netty-transport-4.1.34.Final.jar:4.1.34.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:905) [netty-common-4.1.34.Final.jar:4.1.34.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_201]

2019-04-10 15:34:46.396 ERROR 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.Mono.SwitchIfEmpty.3             : onError(java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host)
2019-04-10 15:34:46.397 ERROR 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.Mono.SwitchIfEmpty.3             : 

java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

2019-04-10 15:34:46.398 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 ! R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Channel cleaned, now 0 active connections and 1 inactive connections
2019-04-10 15:34:46.399 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 ! R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Channel closed, now 0 active connections and 0 inactive connections
2019-04-10 15:34:46.399 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.ReactorNetty               : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 ! R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Non Removed handler: LoggingHandler, context: ChannelHandlerContext(LoggingHandler, [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 ! R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443]), pipeline: DefaultChannelPipeline{(reactor.left.sslHandler = io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler), (reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec), (LoggingHandler = io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler), (ReadTimeoutHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler), (WriteTimeoutHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.WriteTimeoutHandler), (IdleStateHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
2019-04-10 15:34:46.399 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.ReactorNetty               : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 ! R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Non Removed handler: ReadTimeoutHandler, context: ChannelHandlerContext(ReadTimeoutHandler, [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 ! R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443]), pipeline: DefaultChannelPipeline{(reactor.left.sslHandler = io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler), (reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec), (LoggingHandler = io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler), (ReadTimeoutHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler), (WriteTimeoutHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.WriteTimeoutHandler), (IdleStateHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
2019-04-10 15:34:46.399 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.ReactorNetty               : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 ! R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Non Removed handler: WriteTimeoutHandler, context: ChannelHandlerContext(WriteTimeoutHandler, [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 ! R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443]), pipeline: DefaultChannelPipeline{(reactor.left.sslHandler = io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler), (reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec), (LoggingHandler = io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler), (ReadTimeoutHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler), (WriteTimeoutHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.WriteTimeoutHandler), (IdleStateHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
2019-04-10 15:34:46.399 DEBUG 235344 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] reactor.netty.ReactorNetty               : [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 ! R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443] Non Removed handler: IdleStateHandler, context: ChannelHandlerContext(IdleStateHandler, [id: 0xb38d8bca, L:/xx.xxx.x.xxx:55712 ! R:remoteserver.host.com/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443]), pipeline: DefaultChannelPipeline{(reactor.left.sslHandler = io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler), (reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec), (LoggingHandler = io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler), (ReadTimeoutHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler), (WriteTimeoutHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.WriteTimeoutHandler), (IdleStateHandler = io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
2019-04-10 15:34:46.414 ERROR 235344 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] threw exception
```

I see that the connection is not returning to the pool properly. Is there anything I am missing in configuration? Do I have close the connection properly? I assume this should be handled by netty right?

Comment: I have a similar problem, have you solved it?

Answer (score 1):

This question seems similar to [an issue reported to the reactor-netty project](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/764).

It's not clear at this point if the remote server is not closing the connection properly, or if there is/was a bug in reactor-netty that would not manage the connection in the pool as expected.

If this happens still on recent reactor-netty versions, please update this question and/or raise an issue with a tcpdump record and [wire logging](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/764#issuecomment-505581446) to help us figure this out.